# C pass array to a function by pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am new to C and pointers and I'd like know if its possible to pass an array pointer to a function instead of passing the array of characters itself. I am posting the snippet from the code.

```
char ipAddress[24];
int i, j;
for (i = 12; i <= 13; i++)
{
    for (j = 1; j <= 254; j++)
    {
        sprintf(ipAddress,"192.168.%d.%d",i,j);
        runCommand(ipAddress);
    }
}

// ...

int runCommand (char x[24])
{
    // Do stuff.
}
```

Comment: This already passes a pointer.

Comment: You need to specify your problem.

Comment: The array name is always a pointer to the first element of the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are always passed by pointer in C, not passed by value (copyed)

So

```
int runCommand (char x[24]);
```

is close equivalent of

```
int runCommand (char *x);
```

Comment: -1: Inside the function `runCommand(char x[24])`, the value of `sizeof(x)` is `sizeof(void *)` and not 24.  Try it and see.  Ping me a comment when you've fixed this.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes! Strange, but true. No matter compiler sees real type with size it continues emulating `char*` to the end.

Comment: Since my background is basically from Perl,i was thiking more in terms of passing an array reference to a function & deref it later in the function,than passing the array itself..i.ee pass-by-reference not pass-by-value.So,if i am to understand,from my above code,Arrays are always passed by pointer in C to a function,right ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to pass a pointer to an array to a function.  No, it is probably not what you want.

```
int runCommand(char (*x)[24])
{
    if ((*x)[0] == '\0')  // Option 1
        return -1;
    if (x[0][0] == '\0')  // Option 2: equivalent to option 1.
        return -1;
    ...
}

void alternative(void)
{
    char y[24] = "Samizdat";
    printf("%d\n", runCommand(&y));
}
```

That says `x` is a pointer to an array of 24 characters.  Be very careful, though. In general, you do not want to pass a pointer to an array; you just want to pass pointers around.

```
int runCommand(char x[24])  // Or: char *x
{
    if (x[0] == '\0')  // Option 1
        return -1;
    ...
}

void alternative(void)
{
    char y[24] = "Samizdat";
    printf("%d\n", runCommand(y));
}
```